# Assigning dates to rows in my data depending on the number of row in my data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame to which I want to insert dates to each row, this will be based on the number of rows in the data and the length of the event. So for example if my data frame is 20 rows and my event length is of 4 days, rows 1-5 will be the first date, 5-10 the 2nd date and so on. For this example I'm just going to use some dummy data and leave some columns blank as theyre not needed for the dates

So here mydf is nrow = 15 and my event_length = 3. Therefore when I split my df I will have 3 separate dates to use.

```
event_length = 3
dates_to_assign = c(2023-07-24, 2023-07-23, 2023-07-22)

mydf
name     date    
john     NA      
joe      NA
brian    NA
harry    NA
wes      NA
will     NA
dan      NA
william  NA
steve    NA
dom      NA
andrew   NA
shaun    NA
mark     NA
ben      NA
dan      NA
```

What I'm looking for is the first 5 rows to be filled with the oldest date (2023-07-22), 6-10 the middle date (2023-07-23) and the last 5 to be 2023-07-24.

To do this I thought some for of for() loop would be best but wasn't sure on how to move through the rows

Comment: `nrow` is 14. What to do in this case?

Comment: @AndreWildberg Good spot, I'll change it to be 15, although in that case I would just want the last 4 to be assigned the last date

Comment: `2023-07-24` is not a date nor is it a character string representing a date. It means 2023 minus 7 minus 4.

Comment: That is true. I usually use the 20230724 format but had a feeling that would be less popular on here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `each` argument in the `rep` function.

```
# Switching order of dates and using character strings to get your desired output
dates_to_assign <- c("2023-07-24", "2023-07-23", "2023-07-22")

# If nrow(mydf) is not divisible by event_length, add empty rows to mydf such that it is divisible
if (nrow(mydf) %% event_length != 0) {
  mydf[(nrow(mydf)+1):(event_length*ceiling(nrow(mydf)/event_length)),] <- NA
}

# Fill in the dates
mydf$date = rep(dates_to_assign, each = nrow(mydf)/event_length)

# Remove any extra rows that were previously added
mydf <- mydf[!is.na(mydf$name),]
```

**Edit**: Added some code to deal with the case when `nrow(mydf)` is not divisible by `event_length`.

Comment: Looking at this I think rounding the sum of `nrow(mydf) /event_length` to the next integer would work. This can be done by using `ceiling()`.
 
`mydf$date <- rep(dates_to_assign, each = ceiling(nrow(mydf)/event_length))`

Comment: That does not work because the length of the vector produced by `rep(dates_to_assign, each = ceiling(nrow(mydf)/event_length))` would exceed the number of rows in `mydf`, giving you an error when you fill in the date column. I've edited my original answer to deal with the case when `nrow(mydf)/event_length` is not divisible by 0.

Answer (score 1):

we can split the dataframe into even-sized groups using `cut_number`from `ggplot2`. This requires a numerical column, so I first added a `row_n`-column which represents the row number.

```
mydf <- read.table(text="
name     date    
john     NA      
joe      NA
brian    NA
harry    NA
wes      NA
will     NA
dan      NA
william  NA
steve    NA
dom      NA
andrew   NA
shaun    NA
mark     NA
ben      NA
dan      NA", header = T)


event_length <- 3
dates_to_assign <- c("2023-07-24", "2023-07-23", "2023-07-22")

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydf <- mydf %>% mutate(row_n = row_number(),
                group = as.numeric(cut_number(row_n,event_length)),
                date = dates_to_assign[group])
```

```
> mydf
      name       date row_n group
1     john 2023-07-24     1     1
2      joe 2023-07-24     2     1
3    brian 2023-07-24     3     1
4    harry 2023-07-24     4     1
5      wes 2023-07-24     5     1
6     will 2023-07-23     6     2
7      dan 2023-07-23     7     2
8  william 2023-07-23     8     2
9    steve 2023-07-23     9     2
10     dom 2023-07-23    10     2
11  andrew 2023-07-22    11     3
12   shaun 2023-07-22    12     3
13    mark 2023-07-22    13     3
14     ben 2023-07-22    14     3
15     dan 2023-07-22    15     3
```

We can then drop the auxiliary columns again:

```
mydf <- mydf %>% select(-c(row_n,group))
```

```
> mydf
      name       date
1     john 2023-07-24
2      joe 2023-07-24
3    brian 2023-07-24
4    harry 2023-07-24
5      wes 2023-07-24
6     will 2023-07-23
7      dan 2023-07-23
8  william 2023-07-23
9    steve 2023-07-23
10     dom 2023-07-23
11  andrew 2023-07-22
12   shaun 2023-07-22
13    mark 2023-07-22
14     ben 2023-07-22
15     dan 2023-07-22
```

Hope this helps!